# Nefarious user still allowed to contribute?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Yesterday, I flagged an answer from this [user](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/274523/anastasia-nomat) because he/she posted a harmful link which performs a drive-by download attack.

Should not the community ban them network wide?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't confirm whether the link is harmful or not. Ordinarily I'd summarily suspend and destroy such users regardless. We have a dedicated 'Destroy' option for accounts like these:

> This user was created to post spam or nonsense and has no other positive participation

Network-wide suspensions is not something moderators can do. This requires intervention from staff. If the link is indeed harmful, I suppose the Trust and Safety team would be interested in knowing so.

At the bottom of the page you can find the Contact option:

[image: Contact]

Here you can choose to contact Trust and Safety, wanting to report a Code of Conduct violation:

[image: Trust and Safety, Code of Conduct violation]

Give them as much details as possible.

They'll decide whether a network-wide suspension is the right call.

---

Why hasn't the user been suspended yet on *our site*? Well, I didn't handle the flag but a lot of moderators [aren't doing much moderating lately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/269301). So it's entirely possible you'll find users aren't handled as thoroughly as we're all used to at the moment. The content has been taken care of to not unnecessarily endanger people, the rest is of lesser priority.

---

## Update:

User has been destroyed network wide.